# How to update user's feed in Firebase Database when the user follows someone

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am designing an application that each user will a have a timeline (aka feed) based on the posts of his/her followings. In my database, I am keeping the user timeline posts as Shared Key. So each ID in the `feed`subtree belong to a post of someone the user following.

```
"users": {
  "userId-1": { 
    "userName": "Namey McNameface",

    "following": {
      "followingId-1": true,
      "followingId-2": true,
      .
      .
    },
    "followers": {
      "followerId-1": true,
      "followerId-2": true,
      .
      .
    },
    "feed": {
      "postId-1": true,
      "postId-2": true,
      .
      .
    }
  },
  "userId-2": {},
  "userId-3": {},
  .
  .
}
```

When somebody posts something, I am also adding the key of that post to the `feed` of followers of that user.

The problem is that, when somebody starts following someone else, they are not starting to see their older posts. Do you have any idea how to update users timeline immediately after they followed someone?

Note:
This is not a code based problem, its actually a design problem. I am just trying to understand the general idea of user feed in Firebase Database.

**Edit:**

I am using Java and Spring Framework for my server.

The user feeds are time-ordered. So we need to keep this order while adding and removing references to posts.

Thank you.

Comment: Specify your coding lang.

Comment: I don't get the problem, of course the solution is to retrieve the older posts and push them to the user timeline, either contextually or using a worker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the historic posts of a user when you start following them, you will need to read those posts at that time. Since your question contains no information on how you store the posts, this is unfortunately as concrete as I can make the answer.

But if we assume that each user also has a list of their own posts, it could be something like (in JavaScript):

```
function follow(uid) {
  var postsRef = ref.child('users').child(uid).child('posts');
  var feedRef = ref.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('feed');
  postsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    feedRef.child(snapshot.key).set(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, your code is perfectly fine if we wanted to add older posts to the user's feed. But the thing is user's feed is actually ordered by the time of post. We need to keep the order while we are adding new posts to the feed. Of course we can do that in code as well, but wouldn't it be very huge operation to merge those posts into the user feed while keeping them in time-order? Is this the best-practice for user feed?

Comment: The best practice is the one that works optimally for all your app's use-cases. Since we can't know those (likely neither do you), focusing on them now is a case of premature optimization. Writing data in multiple locations is quite common in NoSQL databases. You're essentially making writes more expensive/difficult, so that reads become cheaper/simpler. I highly recommend reading this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).